# HighCharts how to remove display on loading of piechart

Tags: css, highcharts

[image: the empty pie chart]

Above is a picture of my pie chart in Highcharts when it is loading.. the empty circle displays when the pie chart is loading, I would like the empty circle to not display when the pie chart is loading and only display the whole pie chart after it is done loading, Is there an option to do this?

Here is an example js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gdm0wpey/

```
series: [
        {
            name: "Browsers",
            colorByPoint: true,
        }
 ],
```

We see that when the pie chart data is removed, the base empty pie still stays there. I believe that this is connected to getting the base empty pie to be removed when the chart is loading as well. I can't show a live demo of that because it requires loading data from an API

Answer (score 1):

You can hide empty pie series by setting `borderWidth` to 0.

```
    series: [{
        borderWidth: 0,
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4j7fa6d1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.borderWidth

---

Or use `showLoading` and `hideLoading` chart's methods:

```
chart.showLoading();

// async function
    chart.series[0].setData([1, 2, 3]);
    chart.hideLoading();
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kpbLr6n4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#showLoading

Answer (score 0):

One option to remove the border is to set the border width to 0 in the `plotOptions` for `pie`:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   /* ... options ... */
   plotOptions: {
      pie: {
         borderWidth: 0
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option could be:

- Overwrite the class with custom css styles:

Example:

```
/* This is the css class name of the pie chart when has no data: */
.highcharts-empty-series {
  stroke: #ffffff !important; /* the same color of the background in your jsfiddle example. */
}
```

Here is the [modified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/8xvnq153/).

---

Also, consider use the [`noData`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData) option - from the [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData):

> noData
>
> Options for displaying a message like "No data to display". This
> feature requires the file no-data-to-display.js to be loaded in the
> page. The actual text to display is set in the lang.noData option.
>
> ***Requires***
>
> [modules/no-data-to-display](https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js?_ga=2.165351039.1965886995.1621862578-1841060182.1620137969)
>
> ***Try it***
>
> [Line chart with no-data module](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-line)
>
> [Pie chart with no-data module](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-pie)